# Ruby remove blank lines from a file which include spaces

Tags: ruby

I am trying to remove blank lines from a file.

My current code is:

```
 def remove_blank_lines_from_file(file)
   File.write(file, File.read(file).gsub(/^$\n/, '')) 
 end
```

The above code removes only the empty lines, but I also want to remove the lines which include spaces.

How could I do it?

Comment: [strip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-strip) the spaces before calling `gsub` or include the spaces in the regex used by `gsub`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you nevertheless load the whole file into memory, this might be easier to read:

```
File.write(file, File.readlines(file).reject { |s| s.strip.empty? }.join)
```

Just remove those lines, containing the spaces only.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the upvotes is not in fact why we do what we do here :)

Comment: True, but a downvote applied to a good answer is at best confusing to the reader.